Is storing currently focused element in search params abusing their intended functionality
I have a page with a form and table. The form values send a get request with search params e.g: /data?user_id=3&category_id=1 and these are used on the server to make the corresponding db queries and the server responds with the html for the next page.
To make the experience a bit more seamless for the user, I would like to see, if it's possible, to maintain whatever focus was present on the form inputs. For example, the user is browsing for data by checking different field values because they're not sure exactly which value they need.
I can see with JS, it would probably work fairly easily and could maybe store in localstorage or something. However, since my app doesn't really have JS, I would like to avoid adding it if there are solutions. So, I'm thinking about adding to the search query i.e: ?focus=<element_id> e.g: ?focus=user_id.
I don't have huge experience with classic server driven html apps having used a lot of JS driven SPA ..etc, so I don't know if that's considered a good use of search params or too out of scope. I'm thinking the params should be data related more than app state related, and there may be complications with requests etc and redirection and complexity on when to add and remove the param. So, it's probably not a great solution and I would appreciate any other suggestions for preserving focus across pages.
I have HTMX loaded but still considering whether or not to use it. I want to see how far I can get with just HTML, plus, I had some difficulty with HTMX posting the form but wanting the page to redirect with search params.
